# Где писать вызов функции?

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript, html

Привет, друзья!

У меня, наверное, глупый вопрос .)

У меня есть общий файл со скриптами, например main.js и есть много разных страниц, на одной из которых есть форма ('#form'). 
Мне нужно сделать валидацию формы. Т.е. при сабмите должна вызываться функция из main.js

Как правильно сделать: прописать в атрибуте формы вызов функции валидации или в main.js написать что-то типо такого:

```
if( $('#form').length ) {
    validationForm();
}
```

Или еще как-то.

Спасибо.

Comment: При сабмите формы вызывать валидатор, или при потере фокуса определенного поля проверять данные на валидность не отходя от кассы. Так же не забываем проверять все на стороне сервера!

Comment: 1) <form id="fo" onsubmit="validation();">  ??
      2) $('#submitbutton').on('click',validation);

Comment: Palmervan, вы не поняли вопрос =)

Vfvtnjd, да, первое так. И как правильно? Если я сделаю как во втором пункте, то ничего не случиться, если это вызовется на странице где нет формы? Просто проигнорируется?

Comment: Лучше сделать так: вешаем событие на кнопку отправки ,и там решаем отправить форму или нет соответственно результату валидаций.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы сделаете как во-втором пункте, то форма провалидуется в момент загрузки страницы (хотя это зависит от браузера немножко).

Нужно юзать так: [Тынц](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Насчет как правильнее - мне кажется дело вкуса.

Когда код изначально находится на странице, я обычно делаю как на ссылке выше.

Когда я вставляю код скриптом (или после ajax запрос) - я предпочитаю прописывать события сразу в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте так - на странице, где у Вас форма, подключаем файл main.js. И там же, в том же файле можно написать обработчик

```
$('#foo').submit(function(){
  validation();
})
```

Он не вызовется, пока не будет попытки отправить форму.

Comment: файл main.js у меня один для всех страниц. Вопрос в том что если я вызову, как вы написали и формы не будет на странице, то будет ли ошибка или нет?

Comment: нет, ошибки не будет. если формы нет, то обработчик $('#foo').submit(...) просто не вызовется.